# Python Function variable: local and global

Tags: python, function, global-variables, python-2.7, local-variables

I am struggling with local and global variables.

I was doing this:

```
def SomeFunc(Input):
    if Input == 1:
        Input = "True"
    elif Input == 0:
        Input = "False"

RawInput=int(raw_input("Input 1 or 0: "))
SomeFunc(RawInput)
print str(RawInput)
```

and it showed this:

```
>>> def SomeFunc(Input):
    if Input ==1:
        Input = "True"
    elif Input ==0:
        Input = "False"

>>> RawInput = int(raw_input("Input 1 or 0: "))
Input 1 or 0: 1
>>> SomeFunc(RawInput)
>>> print str(RawInput)
1
```

What should I do so that the input will convert to str in the function?

Comment: Use `lowercase_with_underscores` for variable names/functions http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: The best way to do this is to not have any side effects and return the value from the function btw

Comment: if you wanted, you could reduce this to `Input = str(bool(raw_input("Input 1 or 0: ")))`.  The string `'0'` converts to the bool `False` which converts to the string `"False"`

Comment: @xhainingx -- Nope. `bool('0')` is `True` since `'0'` is a non-empty string.

Comment: @mgilson woops, sorry, shouldve been `Input = str(bool(int(raw_input("Input 1 or 0: "))))`

Comment: @xhainingx -- Yeah, that works, but also passes if the user put in '2' which might not be what you want.

Comment: @mgilson true, but the top answer here would cause a ValueError in that case, which I guess is one way to deal with it.  If this was a more realistic function there'd probably be a clearer answer

Comment: @xhainingx -- The top answer here is (currently) mine ;^) and it would cause a `NameError` in the first version I provided -- I guess I should fix that (ValueError is better -- thanks).  But notice below, I suggest a re-write which is almost exactly what you said in function form.  You're right though.  It's too ambiguous to know how to handle that situation from the question.  I just figured it was worth pointing out the difference.

Comment: @mgilson yes a `NameError` of course, I'm really off my python game tonight haha

Answer (score 4):

Input is an `int` which is an immutable object.  In other words, you can't change it anywhere.  However, you can assign it to something else.  One of the tricky things about python is learning that *everything* is just a reference.  When you assign to something, you just change the reference.  Think about your variables as strings which go into boxes.  When you assign to a variable, you put that string in a particular box.  When you assign that variable to something else, you change the box that string goes to.  Of course, when you actually do an addition, you add the contents of the box, not the strings (which is a little confusing).  If you're accustomed to programming in C, it's kind of like everything is a pointer which gets automatically dereferenced (except when you do an assignment).

So, what to do?  The easiest thing is to `return` the value from your function.

```
def some_func(inpt):
    if inpt == 1:
        return "True"
    elif inpt == 0:
        return "False"
    else:
        raise ValueError("WHAT IS THIS GARBAGE? I SAID 0 OR 1!!!!") # ;^)
```

Now you can call your function as:

```
processed_input = some_func(rw_inpt)
```

as a side note, your function can be condensed to:

```
def some_func(inpt):
    return str(bool(inpt))
```

or

```
def some_func(inpt):
    return "True" if inpt else "False"
```

Both of these pass (and return `"True"` if the user puts in any integer that isn't 0).  If you really want to force the user to not put in something like "2", you can do:

```
def some_func(inpt):
    return {1:"True",0:"False"}[inpt]
```

But I wouldn't recommend that one...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one more question for you.
I am doing a hex to dec converter, i want to do a checking for the value if 10 then A, 11 then b etc. and i tried many ways but its working. most important i cant applied the above in the converter.

Comment: @Zaia -- python has that builtin.  See `hex` and `int`.  Specifically, `int(hex(10),16)`  which converts 10 to hex (0xa) and then back to 10 (decimal).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want the argument to be pass-by-reference, but that is not how Python works for basic datatypes. The pythonic way of doing this is as following:

```
def some_func(input):
    if input == 1:
        return "True"
    elif input == 0:
        return "False"
```

And then

```
raw_input = some_func(raw_input)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: You can just do this: `print bool(int(raw_input("Input 1 or 0: ")))`

The more pythonic way of doing it would be as follows:

```
def some_func(x):
    if x == 1:
        return "True"
    elif x == 0:
        return "False"

x = int(raw_input("Input 1 or 0: "))
x = some_func(x)
print x
```

However if you did want to use `global`s you could do it like this but this is really hacky and it isn't one of the good coding practices that python promotes.

```
def some_func():
    global x
    if x == 1:
        x = "True"
    elif x == 0:
        x = "False"

x = int(raw_input("Input 1 or 0: "))
some_func()
print x
```

Some other notes:
Try not to use names like the bultins eg. `Input` and `RawInput` since it makes things unclear and mixes everything up.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do so that the input will convert to str in the
>   function?

```
def SomeFunc(Input):
    as_string = str(Input)
    if Input == '1':
        Input = "True"
    elif Input == '0':
        Input = "False"
```

Note that python has a native boolean type, including the values `True` and `False` already.  You can use the integer value of `Input` as a condition all on its own.

Comment: Haters, please add constructive criticism about down voted answers.